# Visual Studio Cannot connect to local databse (.mdf)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have Installed Visual Studio 2012.after installing it (i think because of installing SQL Server 2012 alongside) it gives me an error when attempting to add local database file.any idea how to configure VS so that it use proper version of sql server.
note that i have tried setting DataConnection from Tools>Options.but no luck.

thanks in advance.

Comment: "It gives me an error". What error?

Comment: connection to sql server database files (.mdf) require sql server 2005 Express or Sql Server 2008 Express to be installed and running in local computer ,...

Comment: Most probably an instance name issue. You have several versions of SQLServer on your machine. You must specify the proper instance name when you connect.

Comment: as i told on question,i have tried to set instance name explicitly and i am sure that instance is running by the way.but still get the error.

Comment: Hi @BehnamEsmaili , could you please post your connection string?